# rasterlite_load - command not found

Tags: sqlite, rasterlite

I am new to SQLite and when I try to import a raster image in a SQlite database that I created using Spatialite_gui, I get this message `rasterlite_load: command not found` after I write the importing line in cmd.exe. What is the issue and how do I fix it?